# keep my android app minimized once app is opened once forever

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which i wanted to remain minimised once the app is opened by the user one time until the device reboots. I read that android home button by default minimises the app but it seems my app gets closed once i clicked home button. if i open my app again,it is showing from login page. i wanted it to open the page which the user is last viewing.

android minimum and target version is 3 and 15 respectively. can anyone let me know how it can be done to serve the mentioned purpose?

Thanks in advance dudes!

Comment: You'll need a service for that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: "if i open my app again,it is showing from login page." ...Are you not saving user preferences?

Comment: of course am saving using sharedpreferences but still i found all other apps getting minimized on pressing home button but still mine is getting exited even without the user explicitly doing it.. am confused of this. also am doubting on target android version. does it have any impact on this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You need multiple things to do.

**Way minimize the app which is already running.**

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

**Resume back to last running activity**

Read about android:launchMode in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) link. I think standard mode is default and that should work for you.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response.i dont need to minimize the app through the app it has to be when user switches to some other task.i found all other apps getting minimized on pressing home button but still mine is getting exited even without the user explicitly doing it.. should the target android version has to be modified? help me narrow down the situation...

Comment: Please read that link in my answer. Keep launchMod default for all activities

Comment: Ya i am already having android:launchmode set to standard.. but still my app is not minimised and its not being shown under recent apps

Answer (score 0):

Just click on **Setting**
And click on **developer Option** & **ON** it Now go down at last and see **Don't keep activities** if it is selected then deselect it.
Your Problem is solved .
No Enjoy Your Android Phone.